# actor critic gradient inconsistent with mathematical proofs

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, actor-critic-methods

From different books and the courses (including Sutton and Barto, page 332 and [cs229 notes, page 222](https://cs229.stanford.edu/main_notes.pdf), the gradient with respect to $\theta$ with baseline is proved as:
$$\bigtriangledown_\theta \eta(\theta)_a = E_{\tau \sim P_\theta}[ \bigtriangledown_\theta \sum_{t=0}^{T-1} log\pi_\theta(a_t | s_t).(G(s_{t}, a_{t}) - V^{\pi}_{\theta}(s_{t}))]$$
But many implemnetations, including [the one on the tensorflow documentations](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/reinforcement_learning/actor_critic), define the gradient as:
$$\bigtriangledown_\theta \eta(\theta)_b =  E_{\tau \sim P_\theta} [\bigtriangledown_\theta[\sum^{T-1}_{t=0} \log\pi_{\theta}(a_{t} | s_{t}).(G(s_{t}, a_{t})  - V^{\pi}_{\theta}(s_{t}))]]$$
That means they move the term $G(s_{t}, a_{t})  - V^{\pi}_{\theta}(s_{t})$ inside the gradient.

But clearly, $\bigtriangledown_\theta \eta(\theta)_a \neq \bigtriangledown_\theta \eta(\theta)_b$, because:
$$E_{\tau \sim P_\theta} [\bigtriangledown_\theta[ \sum^{T-1}_{t=0} \log\pi_{\theta}(a_{t} | s_{t}) V^{\pi}_{\theta}(s_{t})]] \stackrel{product rule}{=} E_{\tau \sim P_\theta} [\sum^{T-1}_{t=0} \log\pi_{\theta}(a_{t} | s_{t}).\bigtriangledown_\theta V^{\pi}_{\theta}(s_{t})] + E_{\tau \sim P_\theta} [ \sum^{T-1}_{t=0} \bigtriangledown_\theta\log\pi_{\theta}(a_{t} | s_{t}) .V^{\pi}_{\theta}(s_{t})] = E_{\tau \sim P_\theta} [\sum^{T-1}_{t=0} \log\pi_{\theta}(a_{t} | s_{t})\bigtriangledown_\theta V^{\pi}_{\theta}(s_{t})] + 0 = E_{\tau \sim P_\theta} [\sum^{T-1}_{t=0} \log\pi_{\theta}(a_{t} | s_{t})\bigtriangledown_\theta V^{\pi}_{\theta}(s_{t})] \neq 0 $$

Did I do something wrong? If not, with what justification people use $\triangledown_\theta \eta(\theta)_b$ instead of $\triangledown_\theta \eta(\theta)_a$?